# Rails STI: SuperClass Model Methods called from SubClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like a little confirmation that I'm doing this correctly. Using rails single table inheritance I have the following models and class method:

```
class PhoneNumber < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.qual?(number)
    klass = self
    klass.exists?(:phone_number => phone_number)
  end
end

class Bubba < PhoneNumber
end

class Rufus < PhoneNumber
end

Bubba.qual?("8005551212")
```

Tests pass and everything seems to work properly in rails console. Just wanted to confirm that I'm not headed for future trouble by using self in the superclass *PhoneNumber* and using that to execute class methods on subclasses from the parent.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks okay to me. You can shorten the method further:

```
class PhoneNumber < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.qual?(phone_number)
    exists?(:phone_number => phone_number)
  end
end
```

Mindful of the this [bug](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/2389) in STI if you override the `qual?` method in the child classes.

**Edit**

Invoking `qual?` method:

```
# out side your STI models
Bubba.qual?("8003455678")
Rufus.qual?("8003455678")
PhoneNumber.qual?("8003455678")

# in the class method of your STI model
qual?("8003455678")

# in the instance method of your STI model
self.class.qual?("8003455678")
```

Comment: Excellent.

So, class methods that are inherited are executed entirely within the scope of the subclass. And therefore specifying the class, ala MyClass.class_method, is not required for class methods.

Comment: I have added some additional information to my answer. Take a look.